# Cannot change shower temperature - Cartridge issue?

Tags: plumbing, shower, valve, cartridge

My shower was remodeled prior to me purchasing the house, it has one lever that controls the water flow and then a knob that controls the temperature. Well, you can turn that knob as much as you want in any direction and the temperature won't change (luckily it's on a decent temperature).

Unfortunately it does not appear that the valve is some standard brand but seems to be Cifial from the googling I have done so it's not like Home Depot is going to have parts. I think I found a replacement cartridge (see link below) but before I drop $141 I would like to have some sort of idea that the cartridge is the likely culprit.

Does replacing the cartridge sound like the right place to start or is there something else I am not aware of that could be causing this?

https://www.fdsupply.com/item/p099-4256/cifial-cartridges/

Here is a picture of the valve that controls the temperature:
[image]

Comment: I think these valves are temp controlled. You set the temp and that is it. It has been quite a few years since installing one and they were quite expensive but prevented scalding. I thought there was some limited adjustments but I don’t recognize your particular valve.

Comment: Well the valve’s only purpose is temp control but the problem is it doesn’t actually adjust. You’re supposed to be able to turn the knob and make it warmer or cooler but it’s stuck.

Comment: Looks to be a an old prima shower huber spa makes these where r u located ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, these do fail.

I have one almost identical to yours and have had to replace the cartridge a few times in 15 years.

Comment: When they fail, do they fail in the way the OPs has failed? i.e. can no longer adjust the temperature?

Comment: It was the issue. Ended up just replacing it to see if that was the cause and it was.

Comment: @FreeMan - yes. In my experience, the amount of movement reduces dramatically, and the ability to maintain temp reduces accordingly. In my case it ends up far too hot.